# Which Linux to install on my i3-3rd gen and 4 GB ram? (I know it is not about ubuntu but this community is nice and helpful)

Tags: system-installation

You can suggest the name and links for it.
I will be installing it through a USB boot drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 2):

puppy linux very light https://puppylinux.com/ or arch if u want to try something new but always try as a vm first before u switch permanently

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu or Xubuntu will be ideal for your machine.